# JPA criteria search property in abstract collection with subclasses

Tags: jpa, inheritance, collections, spring-data, criteria

I am working with Spring data specifications to write a criteria query using JPA criteria API.

I have a class called `Thing` which has a `Set<Characteristic>` attribute.
The class `Characteristic` is an **abstract** class which has an `id` and a few shared basic attributes.

Then I have several concrete classes that extends `Characteristic` and define a `value` attribute.

- `IntegerCharacteristic` which `value` attribute is an `Integer`
- `DecimalCharacteristic` which `value` attribute is a `Double`
- `StringCharacteristic` which `value` attribute is a `String`
- `BooleanCharacteristic` which `value` attribute is a `Boolean`

Each `Thing` can have 0 or many `Characteristic` of any concrete type in his `characteristics` set.

In the database, the class hierarchy is stored with a joined inheritance strategy as so (5 tables) :

- characteristic (id + some common fields)
- integer_characteristic (foreign key + INT value)
- decimal_characteristic (foreign key + DECIMAL value)
- string_characteristic (foreign key + VARCHAR value)
- boolean_characteristic (foreign key + TINYINT value)

I need **with JPA criteria API** to search all things that have at least a Characteristic with the specified value.

I have written a draft of the SQL query that I want to reproduce with JPA criteria API :

```
SELECT DISTINCT thing.id
FROM   thing 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN thing_has_characteristic has_c 
                    ON ( has_c.thing_id = thing.id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN characteristic c 
                    ON ( c.id = has_c.characteristic_id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN integer_characteristic integer_c 
                    ON ( integer_c.characteristic_id = c.id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN string_characteristic string_c 
                    ON ( string_c.characteristic_id = c.id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN boolean_characteristic boolean_c 
                    ON ( boolean_c.characteristic_id = c.id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN decimal_characteristic decimal_c 
                    ON ( decimal_c.characteristic_id = c.id ) 
WHERE  integer_c.value = "9694" 
        OR string_c.value = "9694"
        OR decimal_c.value = "9694" 
        OR boolean_c.value = "9694";
```

When trying to translate this to JPA criteria, I'm stuck because I think I sort of need to build a subquery from the set of Characteristic to distinguish between the four types of Characteristic classes that I have.

Right now, I have tried a small query with only the Integer and String types but I'm confused about how to make it work with the subclass hierarchy of Characteristics.

```
private Specification<Thing> buildSearchSpecificationByCharacteristicValue(String value) {

    return (Specification<Thing>) (root, query, builder) -> {

        SetJoin<Thing,IntegerCharacteristic> integers = root.<Thing,IntegerCharacteristic>joinSet("characteristics", JoinType.LEFT );
        Predicate isInteger;
        try{
            isInteger = builder.equal(integers.get("value"), Integer.parseInt(value));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            isInteger = builder.disjunction();
        }

        SetJoin<Thing,StringCharacteristic> strings = root.<Thing,StringCharacteristic>joinSet("characteristics", JoinType.LEFT);
        Predicate isString = builder.equal(strings.get("value"), value);

        return builder.or(
            isInteger,
            isString
        );
    };
}
```

It produces the following error :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [value] on this 
ManagedType [com.xxxxxxxx.common.domain.DomainObject];
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [value] 
on this ManagedType [com.xxxxxxxx.common.domain.DomainObject]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution for my problem :

Here is an sample with the criteria just for the integer type, but it's implicit how to do it for the other types.

```
return (Specification<Thing>) (root, query, builder) -> {

    Path<Characteristic> characteristics = root.join("characteristics", JoinType.LEFT);

    query.distinct(true);

    Subquery<IntegerCharacteristic> integerSub = query.subquery(IntegerCharacteristic.class);
    Root integerRoot = integerSub.from(IntegerCharacteristic.class);
    integerSub.select(integerRoot);
    integerSub.where(builder.equal(integerRoot.get("value"),Integer.parseInt(value)));

    return builder.in(characteristics).value(integerSub);

};
```

Comment: did you consider using jpql for this case, I think it would be much easier.

Comment: `select distinct o.id
from   thing o
       left join o.thing_has_characteristic has_c 
       left join has_c.integer_characteristic integer_c 
       left join has_c.string_characteristic string_c 
       left join has_c.boolean_characteristic boolean_c 
       left join has_c.decimal_characteristic decimal_c 
where  integer_c.value = "9694"  or string_c.value = "9694" or decimal_c.value = "9694" `